# LLDB doesn't create convenience variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, command, lldb

In an objective-c project, this command works well. but in Swift,

> (lldb) expr unsigned int $foo = 5
>
> error: :1:4: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
>
> int $foo = 5
>
> ```
>  ^
>  ;
> ```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression parser uses the compiler's parser for the language of the current frame.  Presumably you are stopped in a Swift frame, so you have to use correct Swift syntax.  The swift equivalent is of your ObjC example is:

```
(lldb) expr var $foo : Int = 10
```

or since Swift does type inference, you can just say:

```
(lldb) expr var $foo = 10
```